# How can i fix this error of 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, file, kivy, load

I get the following error message and I saw similar question but still not sure how to fix it ,error`:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start :

main.py:

```
def load(self, path, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
        self.text_input.text = stream.read()

    self.dismiss_popup()

def save(self, path, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as stream:
        stream.write(self.text_input.text)

    self.dismiss_popup()
```

Comment: The file you're trying to read is not utf-8, and therefore you can't read it as a text file without knowing more information about it.  Try opening the file with an editor.  Is it a binary file?  Use "rb" and "wb" as the modes for reading or writing.  Is it some other encoding?  Use the appropriate encoding with `encoding=` in the `open()` call.  `encoding="ascii"` tends to be the most resilient.

Comment: Thank you for your response , I want to use it for opening csv files so i changed it as you suggested  :                                                                                                   def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as rb:
            self.text_input.text = rb.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'w') as wb:
            wb.write(self.text_input.text)

        self.dismiss_popup().    , what should i do now ? thanks

Comment: @Anas Could you please update your post rather than submitting the code via a comment?

Comment: The byte 0x89 considered as a character is  `‰` both in Windows-1252 and Latin-1, and that is an unlikely glyph to see at the beginning of a textfile. That suggests that the file you're trying to read is not in fact text at all.